# Android ActionBarSherlock custom topbar?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

How can i apply a custom ActiobbarSherlock to my activities. I am looking for something like this [this](http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?q=android%20foursquare%20application%20screens&hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&biw=1360&bih=654&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsa&tbnid=lfklBUoSthRN-M%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.avc.com/a_vc/2012/07/feature-friday-android-sharing.html&docid=xZbJXrViXMnkYM&imgurl=http://www.avc.com/.a/6a00d83451b2c969e20167689f65f5970b-500wi&w=500&h=889&ei=Bq5TUOW9AYXo0QGszIHoAg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=346&vpy=243&dur=1219&hovh=300&hovw=168&tx=89&ty=162&sig=109393412952342310549&page=1&tbnh=132&tbnw=73&start=0&ndsp=25&ved=1t:429,r:10,s:0,i:101). I know the four square application uses the SherlockActionBar how can i do this?

This is my current style ...

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:background">#449def</item>
    <item name="background">#0099CC</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/gray_seprator</item>
      <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle|homeAsUp</item>
     <item name="displayOptions">showTitle|homeAsUp</item>
</style>
```

Kind Regards

Comment: What do you want to change? background color? Be more specific.

Comment: I want the back button with title. But the Title should be separate from the homeasup button just like in  the screen shot i have showed you.

Comment: I need to customize the layout. I have updated the question to my current style.

Comment: you have to design your own custom view and set in your actionbar like **getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(your_custom_view)**. example of doing this is available in "Demos" in your downloaded sherlock action bar zip file.

Comment: So will this view be only for the left hand corner or for the right hand as well ?

Comment: I have done this. Now how do i get the OnClickLister for the item clicked ?